# NodeJS Parent-Child classes over multiple files

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, module

Coming from C# it is easily possible to have 2 classes, from separate files, referring to each other in a circular relationship. However now in (Node) JS, it appears to be causing issues.

The idea is that I have the following scenario:

```js
// Parent.js
import {Child} from './Child.js'

export class Parent {
  /** @type {Child} */
  child
}
```

```js
// Child.js
import {Parent} from './Parent.js'

export class Child {
  /** @type {Parent} */
  parent
}
```

Is it possible to retain this relationship, without merging the two files together, and resolve the circular dependency?

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: It is easily possible in JS as well, the code you've posted does work as-is. What usually causes issues is attempting to use one of the classes before it is initialised. If you need one class to initialise the other (e.g. in an `extends` clause), you need to take extreme care to import the modules in the right order, in the whole application - in which case it's easier to avoid the circular dependency in the first place.

Comment: So assuming that there is no unexpected behavior or exception thrown, just accept the Circular Dependency warnings that might be thrown?

Comment: You meaning warnings where a linter complains about the circular dependency? Yeah, ignore them as long as it works.